OpenId Connect Authentication only execute MessageRecieved and RedirectToIdentityProvider
I am currently working on a project that requires implementing a Single Sign-On (SSO) login functionality using Microsoft Azure Active Directory (AD) and OpenID Connect. The desired user experience is as follows:

When a user clicks a button on the web page, a Microsoft Authentication page should pop up.
After successful authentication, the user's email address, which was used for Microsoft authentication, should be retrieved.
The user should be automatically logged into the website using the retrieved email address.

So far, I have managed to implement the login functionality through user email and successfully display the Microsoft Authentication page. The authentication process through Azure AD is successful. However, I am facing difficulties in retrieving the user's email and token from the notification.
It is worth noting that my project is based on .NET Framework 4.6.1 and uses Global.asax.cs for configuration instead of Startup.cs or Program.cs.
I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to successfully retrieve the user's email and token after authentication and log the user into the website accordingly. I am attaching the relevant code snippets below for reference.
//Part of the code in StartupOwin.cs

[assembly: OwinStartup("owinauthtest", typeof(XXXX.Web.Security.StartupOwin))]

namespace iWMS.Web.Security
{
    public class StartupOwin
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureAuth(app);
        }

        private void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            var instrumentationKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApplicationInsightsInstrumentationKey"];
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = instrumentationKey;
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer());
            TelemetryConfiguration.Active.TelemetryInitializers.Add(new HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer());

            Debug.WriteLine("Owin auth loading.");
            string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientId"];
            string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:TenantId"];
            string aadInstance = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AADInstance"];
            string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ClientSecret"];
            string authority = $"{aadInstance}{tenantId}";
            app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieManager = new SystemWebCookieManager()
            });

            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie",
                ClientId = clientId,
                Authority = authority,
                RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"],
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri"],
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,
                ResponseType = "token id_token",
                Scope = "openid email profile",
                SaveTokens = true,
                RedeemCode = true,
                
                Configuration = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectConfiguration
                {
                    AuthorizationEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize",
                    TokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId + "/oauth2/v2.0/token"
                },

                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (notification) =>
                    {
                        string expectedState = notification.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.Dictionary["state"];
                        string actualState = notification.ProtocolMessage.State;

                        Debug.WriteLine("AuthorizationCodeReceived");

                        if (expectedState != actualState)
                        {
                            notification.HandleResponse();
                            notification.Response.StatusCode = 403;
                            notification.Response.ReasonPhrase = "Invalid state parameter.";
                            return;
                        }

                        await Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("AuthenticationFailed: " + context.Exception.Message);
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    MessageReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("MessageReceived");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    SecurityTokenReceived = (context) =>
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine("SecurityTokenReceived");
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
                    {
                        var email = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Email)?.Value;
                        HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"] = email;
                        Debug.WriteLine("SecurityTokenValidated: User email: " + email);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    },

                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = notification =>
                    {
                        if (notification.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication)
                        {
                            string state = notification.OwinContext.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseChallenge.Properties.Dictionary["state"];
                            notification.ProtocolMessage.State = state;
                            Debug.WriteLine("state: " + state);

                            notification.ProtocolMessage.Prompt = "consent";
                        }

                        Debug.WriteLine("RedirectToIdentityProvider: Redirecting to identity provider: " + notification.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri);
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}


//Part of the code in Login.aspx.cs
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                Translate(Page.Controls);

            if (HttpContext.Current.Items["UserEmail"]!=null)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("User is authenticated.");
                var email = HttpContext.Current.Session["UserEmail"] as string;
                
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                {
                    //Response.Redirect("/ShowEmail.aspx");
                    TrySSOLogin(email);
                }
                else
                {
                    Message.CssClass = "error";
                    Message.Text = "MS Auth successful, but email not found.";
                }
            }
        }

        protected void MSLoginBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Initiating authentication process.");

                string state = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
                Session["OIDC_STATE"] = state;

                var properties = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationProperties
                {
                    RedirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"]
                };
                properties.Dictionary["state"] = state;

                HttpContext.Current.Session["RunSession"] = "1";
                HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                    properties,
                    OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

                Debug.WriteLine("Authentication challenge sent.");
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect("/Home");
            }
        }

I have tested my variables, such as tenantid, clientid, and clientsecrets, using Postman, and I am able to receive the correct access token. So it seems that the variables is not the key problem.
However, when I switch to the web application, I can only receive debug logs under the MessageReceived and RedirectToIdentityProvider methods. Additionally, I can obtain the state log, but there is a warning log indicating: "The state field is missing or invalid."
I have tried some solutions on stackoverflow, but it seems their solutions doesn't suit me.
